# Find longest common sub-sequence of 3 strings

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Find the longest common sub-sequence of 3 strings of **equal length n.**

I know the dynamic programming algorithm used when using only 2 strings, which is at the end a matrix nxn, so n^2 time and space (correct me if I'm wrong).

With some adaptions on the indexes, it's easy to make the same algorithm on 3 strings. But the time & space complexity become n^3.

My question is, is there a dynamic programming algorithm that is more efficient? The fact that the strings have equal length changed anything in the problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Convert each string into a trie for generating all subsequences.

Intersect the first two tries to come up with a trie for the common subsequences of the first two.  Intersect that with the third to come up with a trie for common subsequences of all three.  Search the last trie for the longest common subsequence.

The result is `O(length_of_sequence * size_of_alphabet)`.  (Yes, this is more efficient than the naive dynamic programming lcs algorithm.)

Here is a Python solution demonstrating this.  Note the careful use of caching so that we avoid creating redundant data structures.

```
from collections import namedtuple

LinkedList = namedtuple('LinkedList', 'value length tail')

class TrieNode:
    last_id = 0

    def __init__(self, char, trie=None):
        TrieNode.last_id += 1
        self.id = TrieNode.last_id
        self.char = char
        if trie is None:
            trie = {}
        self.trie = trie.copy()

def trie_from_string(string):
    trie = {}
    for i in reversed(range(len(string))):
        char = string[i]
        trie[char] = TrieNode(char, trie)
    return TrieNode('start', trie)

def intersect_tries (trie1, trie2):
    intersected = {} # Memoize to avoid repeated work
    def _intersect (t1, t2):
        key = (t1.id, t2.id)
        if key not in intersected:
            trie = {}
            for next_char, next_node in t1.trie.items():
                if next_char in t2.trie:
                    trie[next_char] = _intersect(next_node, t2.trie[next_char])
            node = TrieNode(t1.char, trie)
            intersected[key] = node
        return intersected[key]
    return _intersect(trie1, trie2)

def find_longest_in_trie (trie):
    seen = {} # Memoize to avoid repeated work.
    def _longest(t):
        if t.id not in seen:
            best = LinkedList(length=0, value=None, tail=None)
            for char, inner in t.trie.items():
                candidate = _longest(inner)
                if best.length < candidate.length:
                    best = candidate
            seen[t.id] = LinkedList(
                length = best.length + 1,
                value = t.char,
                tail = best
                )
        return seen[t.id]
    ll = _longest(trie)
    answer = []
    while ll is not None:
        answer.append(ll.value)
        ll = ll.tail

    # drop 'start' and None
    return answer[1:-1]

foo = trie_from_string('hello, world')
bar = trie_from_string('this world is weird')
baz = trie_from_string('have a wonderful day')
print(find_longest_in_trie(intersect_tries(intersect_tries(foo, bar), baz)))
```